# ASE convesion of Trajectory file to XDATCAR

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling, databases, atomic-simulation-environment

The issue here is while converting a TRAJ file to POSCAR, it works. But, for TRAJ to XDATCAR, it shows `TypeError: images should be a sequence of Atoms objects`. (Check below to see the error report)

```
import ase 
from ase.io import read, write
from ase.io.vasp import write_vasp_xdatcar

bec = ase.io.read("./run10/local_minima.traj")
bec_new_pos = ase.io.vasp.write_vasp("local_minima_new.poscar", bec, vasp5=True)
bec_new_xdat = ase.io.vasp.write_vasp_xdatcar("local_minima_new.xdatcar", bec, label=None)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_143176/175431421.py in <module>
      5 bec = ase.io.read("./run10/local_minima.traj")
      6 bec_new_pos = ase.io.vasp.write_vasp("local_minima_new.poscar", bec, vasp5=True)
----> 7 bec_new_xdat = ase.io.vasp.write_vasp_xdatcar("local_minima_new.xdatcar", bec, label=None)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ase/utils/__init__.py in iofunc(file, *args, **kwargs)
    453                 else:
    454                     fd = file
--> 455                 obj = func(fd, *args, **kwargs)
    456                 return obj 
    457             finally:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ase/io/vasp.py in write_vasp_xdatcar(fd, images, label)
    596 
    597     if not isinstance(image, Atoms):
--> 598         raise TypeError("images should be a sequence of Atoms objects.")
    599 
    600     symbol_count = _symbol_count_from_symbols(image.get_chemical_symbols())

TypeError: images should be a sequence of Atoms objects.
```

Comment: Would you be able to convert the error messages to a code block, rather than an image? This will make it more easily searchable if future users have a similar question. It would also help to have your trajectory file or a small example one that gives the same error.

Comment: Sure, I can do that. Good idea, thanks.

Comment: Based on the error, it looks as though the `read` method is just returning a single `Atoms` object, rather than some iterable of `Atoms`. Could you use a `Trajectory` object instead? https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/io/trajectory.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default [ase.io.read](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/io/io.html#ase.io.read) only reads the last frame of the trajectory (an `Atoms` object), you need to specify the `index` argument to read several frames. `index=':'` will read the entire trajectory.

```
import ase 
from ase.io import read, write
from ase.io.vasp import write_vasp_xdatcar

bec = ase.io.read("./run10/local_minima.traj", index=':')
bec_new_pos = ase.io.vasp.write_vasp("local_minima_new.poscar", bec, vasp5=True)
bec_new_xdat = ase.io.vasp.write_vasp_xdatcar("local_minima_new.xdatcar", bec, label=None)
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work, basically, one needs to put iterable of atoms as images.
So, using the trajectory reader should do the trick.

```
import ase
from ase.io import read, write
from ase.io.vasp import write_vasp_xdatcar
from ase.io.trajectory import Trajectory

bec = Trajectory("./run10/local_minima.traj")
bec_new_xdat = ase.io.vasp.write_vasp_xdatcar("local_minima_new.xdatcar", bec, label=None)
```